# Suggestion on remoting (rpc, rmi) for Java SE client-server app?

Tags: java, remoting

I'm absolutely in love with the way GWT does RPC. Is there anything similar for Java SE you have experience with that:

1. Is not spring
2. Doesn't require a Java EE/Servlet container to run the server side
3. Is not RMI that comes with Java SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POJ (Plain Old JSON).

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/). Not true rpc but easy to use and surely a option to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Jini](http://www.jini.org/). Not Spring- or EJB-related, doesn't run in a container, and you can pick the transport.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like distributed computing you could have a look at the [cajo](https://cajo.dev.java.net/) project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sfnrpc (http://code.google.com/p/sfnrpc)
No spring required.
You can run multiple servers within same JVM
You can have a client connect to multiple servers also.
No event style programming, but supports asynch and synch calls over nio.